# Event registration form - How to make one field appear only if another checkbox field was ticked?

Tags: civievent, display, online-registration

In an event registration form, I have some fields which are only relevant in case the user have ticked a specific checkbox (another field).
How can I make these fields appear only when he ticks this checkbox, and disappear if he unticks it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the regular CiviCRM event forms (utilizing profiles) this is only possible with customisations (probably using javascript). In case you are using Drupal you could set up the integration between CiviCRM and teh webform module which allows you to define such conditions (among many other settings such as paged forms, draft saving, advanced styling...).